# Update ProgressBar/UILabel in realtime

Tags: swift

I am using a Lottie animation library and trying to show progress of an animation with a progress bar, or as a number from 0-1 in a label, but updated in real time.

I tried changing those values on a button or swipe, and it works great. But i don't know how to update the values in real-time without user interaction.

I also tried DisptachQueue but it does not work :/ I realize this is probably a bit bacis, but i tried looking for answer on multiple websites to no avail.

Lottie has a "animationProgress" property so my idea was to send that info to the bar or the label.

Tnx!

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

// Modify progress value of a progress bar. ("animationProgress returns CGFloat")
  self.progressBar.progress = Float(self.animationView.animationProgress)

// Returning same value but as String to the label.
  self.progressLabel.text = 
  String(Float(self.animationView.animationProgress))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing a one-time read from `self.animationView.animationProgress`. In Lottie, you set this property to determine how far along the animation is. Often this is calculated in `scrollViewDidScroll` or similar delegate method.

So you need to set the progress bar progress at the same time you set the Lottie `animationProgress`.

For example:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let progress = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.contentSize.width

    animationView.animationProgress = progress
    progressBar.progress = Float(progress)
    progressLabel.text = "\(progress)"
}
```

As a side note, you can more easily convert numbers to strings using string interpolation, like `"\(progress)"`.

Comment: Ah right, i know about string interpolation but for some reason totally spaced out :) Tnx!

As for the new function. Not sure where should i call it afterwards? I don't use any scrollViews. I did add the scrollViewDelegate but still not quite sure how it fits in?